# How to add extra content to home page of Magento programmatically?

Tags: magento2

I'm totally new at Magento 2.
I want to add content to home page.

This is my code:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
</module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_Module',
__DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/content.phtml

```
<h1>Home page extra content</h1>
```

What are next steps that I should do to to make heading appear in home page?

Comment: why you have to create custom modules? from admin.  Content>Pages> and find out  your  home page  and put the content section

Comment: I want to use modules, because later I'm gonna add some data to them that can't be added using admin page. I want to understand how to do it with code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this but you probably don't need a custom module.

Assuming you need to include content from a phtml file you can simply add something like this into the Design > Layout Update XML section of the Homepage through the admin

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your_block_name" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/your_content.phtml">
        </block>
```

This would then look to load a your_content.phtml file from YOUR_THEME_PATH/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/ and add it to the header container.

If you just wanted static content you can do this through the admin without any coding :

- Setup a Static Block ( Content > Blocks > Add New Block )
- Setup a Widget ( Content > Widgets > Add New )
- Specify Widget type as CMS Static Block
- Specify Layout Updates including Page and Container where it should show
- Chose your Block froms step 1

Answer (score 0):

refer this link
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cms-pages-programmatically.html
through this you can create cms page and can add content to home page